# Как сделать редирект?

Tags: jquery, redirect, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Как сделать такой редирект: человек зашел на страницу, и его перекидывает обратно, на страницу, с которой он пришел, с добавлением определенного якоря.

Например:
Сейчас человек находится по адресу **site.ru/index.html**, переходит по адресу **site.ru/page.html**, и его перекидывает обратно, и добавляется якорь, **site.ru/index.html#yakor**. И главное, чтобы с какой страницы бы он не перешел на **site.ru/page.html**, его всегда возвращало туда, откуда он пришел + якорь.

Comment: Сделал вот так **window.location.href = document.referrer + "#test";** и все заработало. Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть чудесное свойство `document.referrer`. Там лежит как раз предыдущая ссылка, т.е. откуда юзер пришел. Вот оно вам и нужно.

```
if (document.referrer) {
    window.location.href = document.referrer + "#yakor";
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, для modx revo не подходит. Редирект идет на /undefined/

Comment: Обновил ответ.